# How to get notified when a logic app is created

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azureportal, azure-alerts

I currently work with a small development team and I would like an email notification to be sent to me upon creation of a new logic app which would then allow me to configure new alerts for each new one to say if logic has experience a failure of some sort. Right now I constantly have to check the logic apps in the portal to see if any new ones have been created as of late. I couldnt find any info on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the REST API's or SDK's to run a job every minute or so to check for new LogicApps.  You just need to store the state of anything existing to make sure you know the before and after.  Use an Azure Function or something.  I tend to find the PowerShell approach to be quite useful for this kind of thing ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/?view=azps-8.3.0

Comment: On that, you may be able to automate the alerts if you find a new app rather than handling the alerting manually after you actually determine that a new app has been created.  You should look into that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating an alert on activity logs, you can look at the newly created logic app in your activity log and create an alert. You can also use these alerts to trigger emails https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-new-alert-rule